# Ubuntu (alternate) server 18.04: no network interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 using the alternate server installer. During the installation no network interfaces were detected.

I could not figure out how to setup networking (neither ethernet nor wifi). For wired networking I have to use a usb Type-C adapter (Dell XPS 15).

Moreover, ifup/ifdown are not installed. How can I configure the network? I eventually want to install the Ubuntu-desktop. The reason I went with the alternate installer is because I wanted more control on the partitioning than the standard installer allows.

In `/etc/network/interfaces` I had added:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlp2s0
wpa-ssid <essid>
wpa-psk <pass>
```

`ip add show` shows:

```
1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu ##### qdisq noqueue state UKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopbac 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet <ip> scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2so: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu #### qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <mac> brd <brd>
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` outputs:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

`systemctl status systemd-networkd` reports:

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
```

By the way `lshw` shows:

```
network DISABLED
```

Comment: run `ip add show` and post the results!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I added that it shows `lo` and `wkp2s0`

Comment: Is that all it showed?

Comment: No. I updated it excluding addresses

Comment: Were there any specific error messages shown while installing as to why no interface was detected? Please run `systemctl systemd-networkd` and lets see if your `networld` is running!

Comment: Do you wish to use wireless or ethernet? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: I would like both. Updated with the requested results.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen `systemd-networkd` following `systemctl` does not exist!

Comment: My bad it should be `systemctl status systemd-networkd`!!!!

Comment: Your `ip addr show` doesn't include ethernet. As well, we doubt that it is named eth0. Please clarify. I will propose an answer covering wireless only at this time until there are further details.

Comment: @chili555 probably because I do not have the adapter plugged in. The ethernet is received through the usb type-C adapter. I remember it was eth0 when I used to connect on my ubutnu desktop (on this laptop).

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen updated

Comment: Start that service with `sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd && sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen done, it's active. What then?

Comment: Now connect your ethernet cable and let's see how networkd handles it.

Comment: When I said it is active I was referring to the wifi `wlp2s0`. The `eth0` is not shown in `ip addr show` as I do not have it connected (not with me right now). I will try it about 2 hours when I have it with me.

Comment: I eventually tried it. No connection.

Answer (score 4):

Networking in Ubuntu Server 18.04 and later is handled by netplan and no longer in /etc/network/interfaces. Please remove your additions to that file.

Please edit your /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file to read:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Please note that the access point name and password are enclosed in quotation marks. Also, netplan is very specific as to indentation and spacing. Please proofread carefully.

After saving the file, please do:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot. Check to see if you connected. Do you have an IP address?

```
ip addr show
```

Are you connected?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: No it does not connect. No IP

Comment: Well, I am very embarassed! I warned about intentation and made just such a mistake myself! Please see my edit above in a few moments. After making the correction, again run: `sudo netplan generate` followed by: `sudo netplan apply` Note and post any errors or warnings. Sorry for my misstep.

Comment: No problem. I tried it but it doesn't work. I mean I don't have a connection.

Comment: Is there any clue in the log? `dmesg | grep wlp` Please edit your question to show the result.

Comment: After a fresh boot I get `wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0`

Comment: I had something else in `/etc/netplan/01-netcdg.yaml`. I was testing something yesterday. After changing it back `dmesg` also shows `wlp2s0: link is not ready`. No ip address though and ping returns `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Comment: It's time to dive deep. Please download and run the wireless script from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com